# How do I project part of one screen onto a second screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors

How do I project part of one screen onto a second (dual) screen, ideally with Windows or Linux?

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Use multiple monitors where on one screen, I can see the entire screen, while on the other screen I can only see a section of the first screen.

Answer (score 0):

One kind of hackey way to do this

1.) have a screenshot software record the first screen, and mirror it on the 2nd..

http://camstudio.org/

2.) use the zoom features of your recording software to zoom in exclusively to where you need to see..

problem is it's going to look funny, depending on how the zoom is implemented.  Other than that I cannot think of a way to do what you're asking.